# How to run a LINQ sub-query using the Orchard CMS ContentManager? Nhibernate issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, orchardcms, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to use the ContentManager to query for content items with values that are in a list.

```
var matchingItems = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<ItemPart, ItemPartRecord>()
.Where(o => !categories.Any() || categories.Any(c => c == o.Category))
.List()
.Select(o => o.ContentItem.As<CommonPart>().Container.ContentItem)
.Distinct();

return matchingItems;
```

The code compiles fine but when the query runs it throws a null reference exception from NHibernate.Linq;

> at Hibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.GetExistsCriteria(MethodCallExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitAndAlsoExpression(BinaryExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.WhereArgumentsVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.RootVisitor.HandleWhereCall(MethodCallExpression call)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.RootVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression expr)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
>      at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NHibernateQueryTranslator.Translate(Expression expression, QueryOptions queryOptions)
>      at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.Where[TRecord](Expression`1 predicate, ICriteria bindCriteria) in c:\TFS\MySite\Source\Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs:line 104
>      at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.Where[TRecord](Expression`1 predicate) in c:\TFS\MySite\Source\Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs:line 94
>      at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentQuery.ContentQuery`2.Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentQuery<T,TR>.Where(Expression`1 predicate) in c:\TFS\MySite\Source\Site\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentQuery.cs:line 318
>      at MySite.Items.Services.ItemSearchService.GetItems(ItemSearchFilterRequest filters)
>      at MySite.Items.Controllers.ItemSearchController.ReturnFilteredItemData(ItemSearchFilterViewModel model)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__41()

After looking online, it looks like as though NHibernate can't handle sub-queries? Does anybody know how I can run a sub-query using the ContentManager in Orchard CMS?

Comment: You can't. Try to express this with joins instead.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done with joins. It's just a simple 'SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.Category IN (cat1, cat2, cat3)'. I thought something like this would have been needed before... Either way it can't be done can it so I'll try a different approach.

Comment: That looks like a completely different query, but I may be wrong as the formatting of your code is not very readable.

Comment: I was having problems with the formatting so just put it on one line... Some of the data was stored in an external database so we're making a call to it directly and then using the returned array of Ids to query the content manager for the applicable content items. As Piotr pointed out, I should have been using Contains() rather than the Any() extension method to generate the SQL that I was expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use LINQ expressions inside the `Where` clause. NHibernate doesn't know how to interpret that.

Instead, use a list method `Contains` there, ie.

```
(...).Where(o => categories.Contains(o.Category))
```

This will be interpreted by NHibernate correctly and translated to `IN(...)` clause.